# Executing a main class and saving output using maven

Tags: java, ant, maven, maven-3

I'm currently converting my ANT build files to maven and is running into some problems.

I have some classes which automatically generates documentation files for themselves if you run their main-method. A part of my build process is to run these main methods, save the output to textfiles and then upload them to the project website.

My ANT-target looks something like this:

```
<target name="generate-protocol-doc" depends="build">
   <java classname="abc.Protocol" output="builds/protocol.txt">
     <classpath refid="classpath" /> 
   </java>
</target>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in maven?

Comment: Maven expect to have plugins to perform tasks. There is a plugin which performs ant tasks which you should be able to use to perform any task not easily converted from ant.

Comment: Yeah, the plugin Antrun worked, I'll post my solution for future reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin called Antrun as Peter Lawrey pointed out which let's you run native Ant code in maven. Here's my final solution:

```
<build>
<!-- ... -->
<plugins>
<!-- ... -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <!-- It won't output to file unless the vm forks, apparently -->
            <java classname="abc.Protocol" output="builds/protocol.txt" fork="true"> 
                <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
            </java>
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- ... -->
</plugins>
<!-- ... -->
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maven exec plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

Comment: Any clue how to capture the output and store it to file?